# Janks in a ListView from API?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some troubles with flutter's ListView. I've written my own API for this app. It gives me an object, which has "URL", "text" and other fields. I don't know why, but this ListView is so janky! It is not always, it is like stutters in games. This red line(from the screenshot below) is shown when I get a small stutter, but sometimes they are bigger.  Actually, I've tried a lot to optimize it. Here is a GitHub for this project  [clck](https://github.com/hawkkiller/newsapp).
Some news providers don't even have "photo", but it is janky without too.
Also, when I upload more and more articles it starts stuttering more and more.

Dev tools:

Raster max ms - ~13ms/frame
avg ~5ms/frame

[devtools1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDPdz.png)

[devtools2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lm67r.png)

[devtools3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvLkG.png)

[janks1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxNb2.png)

[janks2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQZzp.png)

I would be grateful if you could help me. Thanks.

Comment: Can you guide me to exact location of the `ListView` in question? The file in the repo where you notice the issue?

Comment: It locates in lib/news/components/body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the code above the widget uses `ListView` try using the `ListView.builder` variant of the `ListView` this will build only the items currently visible on the screen.
2. Also avoid `shrinkWrap` if possible, as its an expensive operation, more info mentioned in the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html)

```dart
ListView.builder(
  controller: _controller,
  itemCount: c.newsList.lenght,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) => NewCard(
            article: element,
            isLoading: false,
          )
  physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
);
```

Comment: OK.I will try it soon and give you a feedback, because now I  going to go to sleep. All in all, thank you.

Comment: I 've tried it. Check it on my github, please! However, there are still some janks. https://imgur.com/zuMFzLx https://imgur.com/YTNWcka

Comment: I will need more context to understand what more to optimize next.